# JAX-WS LogicalHandler & SOAPHandler

Tags: asynchronous, jax-ws

I am writing a Java SOAP Client where multiple responses comes back asynchronously into a Client WebService.
Since the response are asynchronous the client must pass in a **MessageId** into the SOAPHeader.  The multiple responses will then pass back the same **MessageId** enabling the client to map up their requests with the many responses.

I have two Handler (Protocal and Logical).  My SOAPHandler is picking up the **MessageId** and LogicalHander is picking up the **Payload** or real response.   I wanted to hook these two pieces of information together somehow.

My problem is I have two different pieces of code one pulls **MessageId** and the other the **Payload** but I don't have a way of attaching the two reliably.

I am not sure if I am over looking something.  Can I pull both the Header and Payload from a Protocal or Logical handler?

Comment: Hi @Peter did you considered accepting the answer?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it all in the SOAP Handler.

> "JAX-WS supports two types of SOAP message handlers: SOAP handlers and
>   logical handlers. SOAP handlers can access the entire SOAP message,
>   including the message headers and body. Logical handlers can access
>   the payload of the message only, and cannot change any
>   protocol-specific information (like headers) in a message."

see [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/writing-a-handler-in-jax-ws.html) for some explanation, and a nice picture :)
also you can read Oracle documentation [Overview of SOAP Message Handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html):

Comment: thanks for the link to the documents.  This is very helpful.  I will try to pull the payload out of the SOAPHeader.